# CSS3 transform on JQuery fadeIn() not working

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

I'm trying to get some content to flip and fade in/out on click. Seems simple but I'm having some difficulty!

I'm using JQuery's `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` methods, and CSS3 transform to achieve this, but currently it only flips when it fades out. I'm sure I'm doing something really stupid but I can't figure it out.

Here's a fiddle with what I've done so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

http://jsfiddle.net/ptfy42rb/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's better to use `show()` and `hide()` instead `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()`, because then all the transitions are made by CSS, which is recommended. And also you need to use a `callback` function and `setTimeout` to work properly.

Relevant code:

```
$('.click').click(function() {
    if (lightbox.hasClass('hidden')) {
        lightbox.show(0, function(){ // Add class when show is completed
            lightbox.addClass('visible');
            lightbox.removeClass('hidden');
        });
    } else {
        lightbox.addClass('hidden');
        lightbox.removeClass('visible');
        setTimeout(function(){ // Hide lightbox when transition is completed
            lightbox.hide();
        }, 400);
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/ptfy42rb/4/)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a timing issue. Using the `dequeue` option with `fadeIn` solves it.

```
if (lightbox.hasClass('hidden')) {
    lightbox.fadeIn({queue: false, duration: '400'});
    lightbox.addClass('visible')
    lightbox.removeClass('hidden');
} else {
    lightbox.addClass('hidden')
    lightbox.removeClass('visible');
    lightbox.fadeOut(400);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jessikwa/ptfy42rb/5/

Comment: Thanks! This fixed the issue but I'm going to replace fadeIn() and fadeOut() with show() and hide() as recommended by @lmgonzalves :)